# Apache Karaf feature:repo-add fails in first run and succeeds in second run

Tags: maven, nexus, apache-karaf, karaf, pax

I have an annoying problem in Apache Karaf 3.0.2. I want to add a feature repository. It is located in my private Nexus Snapshot Repository and protected by username and password. Everything is correctly stated in my `settings.xml`

~/.m2/repository/settings.xml:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>test</id>
        <username>karaf</username>
        <password>karafpass</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central, \
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=spring.ebr.release, \
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external@id=spring.ebr.external, \
http://zodiac.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=gemini, \
http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group@id=apache@snapshots@noreleases, \
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots@id=sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@norelease, \
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots@id=ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases, \
http://192.168.178.25:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots@id=test@snapshots@noreleases
```

The command to add the feature repository:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:com.test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
```

In the first try I get:

```
Error executing command: Error resolving artifact com.test:com.test.feature:xml:features:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact com.test:com.test.feature:xml:features:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
```

Why does it fail? The error statement is right, but why is the artifact not found in my Snapshot-Repository? Here is what I can see in my Nexus `request.log`:

```
192.168.178.25 - - [25/Dez/2014:15:44:40 +0100] "GET /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 0
192.168.178.25 - - [25/Dez/2014:15:44:43 +0100] "GET /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.test.feature-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-features.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 0
192.168.178.25 - - [25/Dez/2014:15:44:43 +0100] "GET /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.test.feature-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-features.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 1289
```

The problem is the `401` in the first line which hinders karaf from getting `maven-metadata.xml` to form the subsequent commands right. Why? All credentials are part of my M2 `settings.xml`, just use them!

The next try with the same command succeeds and the `request.log` says:

```
192.168.178.25 - - [25/Dez/2014:15:59:02 +0100] "GET /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 1029
192.168.178.25 - - [25/Dez/2014:15:59:02 +0100] "GET /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 40
192.168.178.25 - - [25/Dez/2014:15:59:03 +0100] "GET /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.test.feature-1.0.0-20141224.100146-1-features.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 1086
192.168.178.25 - - [25/Dez/2014:15:59:04 +0100] "GET /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/test/com.test.feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.test.feature-1.0.0-20141224.100146-1-features.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 40
```

Please, I require your help? How can I get rid of that problem?

Comment: This looks like you are using Nexus 3 ... right?

Comment: I am using Nexus OSS 2.11.1-01.

Comment: Nexus has issues at times in indexing.  You can delete and create the artifact in the nexus again.  Then remove the specific artifact in the .m2 cache of the karaf server.  You can then do a feature url refresh which should bring the new artifact for you.